# Cómo eliminar un dato de un vector en PSEint

Tags: pseint

estoy tratando de realizar un algoritmo para eliminar un dato que está almacenado en un arreglo en Pseint, encuentro el dato pero la verdad no sé cómo es la instrucción para eliminar dicho dato de un vector.

Este es el código:

```
     Escribir "Eliminar Contacto";
                Escribir "Escriba el nombre del contacto a eliminar";
                Leer nombre;
                Para iterador <- 1 Hasta n Con Paso 1 Hacer
                    si nombres[iterador] == nombre Entonces
                        Limpiar Pantalla;
                        Escribir "Eliminando contacto...";
                        //Eliminar dato de un arreglo
                    FinSi
                FinPara
```

Answer (score 0):

Nose si hay un método para eliminar el elemento del arreglo pero lo que si puedes hacer si es un arreglo de Caracteres es asignarle a la posicion deseasa un ""

```
 Escribir "Eliminar Contacto";
            Escribir "Escriba el nombre del contacto a eliminar";
            Leer nombre;
            Para iterador <- 1 Hasta n Con Paso 1 Hacer
                si nombres[iterador] == nombre Entonces
                    Limpiar Pantalla;
                    Escribir "Eliminando contacto...";
                    nombres[iterador] = ""
                FinSi
            FinPara
```